# Connecting to a WPA2 network

Tags: networking

1. For connecting to networks use WPA/WPA2 with PSK, from [here](https://superuser.com/a/701457/9265)

   ```
      wpa_passphrase your_network_name your_password > wpa.conf
      ifconfig wlan0 down
      ifconfig wlan0 up
      iwconfig wlan0 essid your_network_name
      wpa_supplicant -B -Wnl80211 -i wlan0 -c wpa.conf
      dhclient wlan0
   ```

   What does `iwconfig wlan0 essid your_network_name` do?

   Is `iwconfig wlan0 essid your_network_name`  needed? I saw other webpages which doesn't have this step.
2. `lshw` shows the driver for `wlan0` is `iwlwifi`. My wifi adapter is
   PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh]. But why:

   ```
   $ sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Diwlwifi -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf 
   Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant 
   wlan0: Unsupported driver 'iwlwifi'
   ```

   Do I need to write `-Diwlwifi` or `-D iwlwifi`? Both have the above
   problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `iwconfig wlan0 essid your_network_name` sets the ESSID your card should attempt to connect to. If there are multiple hotspots with the same name, the card would attempt authentication with all of them until it finally associates and authenticates with the right one. This is optional, given that you provide your BSSID using `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK ap 00:60:1D:01:23:45`
2. Try to either use wext or nl80211 (wext recommended, because nl80211 is said to be obsolete). They will take care of interfacing with your wifi card. Basically your command should be:

   `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

   Spaces don't really matter. `-Dwext` and `-D wext` are supposed to be the same.

Comment: thanks. 1. is BSSID same as ap? Is this step necessary, given that ISSD is given to wpa_passphrase and stored in wpa.conf? 2. why not iwlwifi, the wifi adapter driver? Is wext my wifi adapter's driver?

Comment: 1. Yes, BSSID is the same as AP. The BSSID is simply the AP's MAC address. This step is necessary. You have to let the wifi card know what hotspot to connect to, right? So either ESSID (general) or BSSID (Specific AP) would work, BSSID working faster (your card doesn't have to try to authenticate to all those AP's with the same name.

Comment: 2. I think wext is the one interfacing with iwlwifi. wext provides the interface necessary for iwlwifi to understand your commands. Wext takes your parameters and tells iwlwifi what to do.

Comment: 1. ISSD is given to wpa_passphrase and stored in wpa.conf in the first command in the quote. Then wpa.conf is referred to in the last command `wpa_supplicant -B -Wnl80211 -i wlan0 -c wpa.conf` in the quote. Is it necessary to run `iwconfig wlan0 essid your_network_name` or `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK ap 00:60:1D:01:23:45`?

Comment: 2. Is `wtext` my wifi adapter's driver or something else? Is it at a lower or higher level than `iwlwifi`?

Comment: To be clear, it's SSID (or ESSID, they're the same).  If you passed the SSID (with passphrase) thru wpa_passphrase, you do not need to run `iwconfig wlan0 essid your_network_name`. `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` actually reads the configuration file and does the configuration for you, so you don't have to type all those commands on #1 every time you connect to the network.  Do note you want >> instead of > in `wpa_passphrase your_network_name your_password > wpa.conf`. > overwrites the whole file while >> appends to file.

Comment: 2. `wext` is higher than `iwlwifi`. `wext` provides the bridge between `wpa_supplicant` and `iwlwifi`. `iwlwifi` is the bridge between `wext` (or the system in general) and the wifi card itself.


`wpa_supplicant -> wext -> iwlwifi -> wifi card`

Comment: Do mark as answer if this helped you. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks. (1) if Iwtext isn't  my wifi adapter's driver, what is it? Is it a device file? (2) Why `-D` in manpage of `wpa_supplicant` says it expects a driver, if lwtext isn't a driver?

Comment: I like to see wext as a "driver to a driver". `iwlwifi` is the card's driver. Wext is the thing that enables communication between `wpa_supplicant` and `iwlwifi`

Comment: Thanks. is `wext` mentioned in the output of some command? I never seen it before. `iwlwifi` is in the output of `lshw` for my wifi adapter at least.

Comment: `wpa_supplicant --help` Yup. It's there. Anyways, please mark this as the answer if it helped (Checkmark below the upvote/downvote thing on the side). Thanks! :)